# Realize an OSC listener and message-modifier

Tags: java, python, osc

I have installed touchOSC on my phone and I would like to control the score editor Musescore (that accept OSC messages).

Problem: touchOSC send messages always together with a double value while a lot of controls I'd like to use in Musescore has a method signature with no arguments at all (e.g. /actions/play to start playback of the score).

So, the only way I'm figuring out right now is to write a sort of listener (python? java?) listening to touchOSC, changing the message (typically, cutting the double value) and sending the modified message to the right port for Musescore.

I have some Java skills but I wouldn't know how to manage OSC message.
I have also downloaded a python library named simpleOSC but I have 0 skills in python.

Could someone help?
Thank you very much

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleOSC

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use PureData for this: https://puredata.info/

It's free, open-source, cross-platform and is equipped to do what you want: Receive OSC messages and filter/modify/forward them, all in a visual, flow-based programming way.

Here's the "TouchOSC | OSC with PureData" tutorial, which has some basic example PD patchers as well to get you started:
https://hexler.net/docs/touchosc-getting-started-osc